# Where can I request an API key in the docs?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Can you mention the possibility of requesting an API key in [the docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)? It was displayed for the [1.0 API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the very first paragraph in the section *General*:

> Applications should be registered on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) to get a request key. Request keys grant more requests per day, and are necessary for using access_tokens created via [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Click the first link, and there's the registration form.

Comment: Hmmmmm... Looks like i was looking too hard for API key. :-)